# How to get last message from every two users conversation

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am creating message conversation script, I want to get last message from every two users conversation. MY script display all from_id messages. Any one can help me I have lot of tried.

My database pm table structure

```
id  from_id    to_id     msg               sent_date
1   2          3         hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20
2   3          2         fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58
3   2          3         hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34
4   5          2         hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40
```

Here is my source code

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $to_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from pm where to_id=? or from_id=?  ")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $to_id, $from_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

<?php echo $row['msg']; ?>

<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "NO MESSAGES";
}

?>
```

Comment: What isn't working the way you'd like it to? What results are you presently getting as opposed to the desired results? You didn't say.

Comment: what you want here? you want to print only last message of the user. am i right?

Comment: my script display from_id all messages but i want to get all conversation last message two users

Comment: you are getting only the data of "from_id", and you want to print sender and receiver both data

Comment: you are correct i want to display two users last message

Comment: bro. actually i am not familiar with prepared statement.. ;)

Comment: i can solve your problem using core php

Comment: yes i want to display sender and receiver both data last message

Comment: @MUFAzmi - The only thing prepared statements changes in the queries are how you use user data. For example: You write `column = ?` instead of something like `column = '$variable'`. Other than that, all SQL is still the same so if you know a query for solving the OP's issue, it's still very much valid.

Comment: i can't understand my script problem. can you solve my problem please

Comment: ok wait, i am trying to solved

Comment: MUFAzmi  i am waiting for your answer plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, it was too hard for me to do all this in a SQL query. This solution is really not the best but the best I was able to come up with.

```
$sessionId = <session id variable>;

if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ? ORDER BY sent_date DESC")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $sessionId, $sessionId);
    $stmt->execute();
}



$tempArray = array();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      if (!in_array($row['to_id'].$row['from_id'], $tempArray)) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['from_id']." - " . $row['to_id']." ". $row['msg']. " - " .$row['sent_date'];
      }

      array_push($tempArray, $row['from_id'].$row['to_id']);
      array_push($tempArray, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);


    }
} else {
    echo "NO MESSAGES";
}
```

Image of every last message from every conversation:

[image: image of every last message from every conversation]

Comment: Let's discuss it here. Can you try to explain agian what's not displayed

Comment: Didn't quite understand this sentence: "when i send last as message it not showing"

Comment: your script display from id data only

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think so.

Comment: can you add bind parameters with

Comment: Yes that is possible

Comment: yes but i want to get session user own messages only

Comment: I fix no problem

Comment: this script  showing all messages other users discussed can you add session with bind parameters

Comment: brother it's working better, i am really very happy today, thank you very much bro, lot of thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! :D

Comment: Can ýou up vote my answer? I need 5 more points. Would make me really happy :)

Comment: @JonathanThunberg  can you little more help me?

Comment: @krrajesh Sure. Open a new question :P

Comment: @JonathanThunberg can you one more help plz

Comment: Maybe tomorrow. If it is a small one. I have much to do right now :/

Comment: @JonathanThunberg can you one more help plz

Comment: here is my link plz help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429426/how-to-update-session-empty-value

Comment: @krrajesh Sry I really want to. But I have too much to do right now.