# How to update session empty value

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am creating message conversation delete script in PHP MYSQLI. I am trying to update session empty value. My problem I can update `from_delete` column. But I can't update incoming message column `to_delete`. I want to update `from_delete` or `to_delete` columns empty session value.

Here is my pm table

```
id  from_id     to_id    msg               sent_date              from_delete      to_delete
1   2           3        hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20    0                3
2   3           2        fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58    0                2
3   2           3        hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34    0                3     
4   5           2        hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40    0                2
```

Here is my source code

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE pm SET from_delete = ? or to_delete =? WHERE id=? ");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $session_id, $session_id, $id);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo"deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Failed to delete<br/>";
}
```

Comment: What does it mean `from_delete = ? or to_delete =?`? What do you mean *"I want to create always from_delete or to_delete should be updated empty session value."*?

Comment: i can update from_delete column my session id but i cant update to_delete my session id

Comment: Have you tried `SET from_delete = ?, to_delete =?`

Comment: yes i have checked but same i cant update to_delete column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to read first and check if message belongs to the current user as sender or receiver, then delete for him. But you can try to do both just setting the right filters.

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}
// Mark from_delete only if user is the sender
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE pm SET from_delete = ? WHERE id = ? AND from_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $session_id, $id, $session_id);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo"deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Failed to delete<br/>";
}
// Mark to_delete only if user is receiver
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE pm SET to_delete = ? WHERE id = ? AND to_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $session_id, $id, $session_id);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo"deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Failed to delete<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I checked your script but sender or receiver not changing anything

Comment: Make some debug to see if values are right or not, var_dump($id, $session_id); Then, print the query and test it on PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: not showing any error message, display deleted successfully message but not changing anything PhpMyAdmin

Comment: That message means that query was executed successfully but not that any change has been made in database, that's why you need to check data and query to find what's wrong.

Comment: i cant understand i checked lot of but same please bro help me

Comment: @previn, I'm trying. Please include this line at the end of the script and tell me what do you get: **echo "[$id][$session_id]";** and please add a screen capture of your pm table from PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: help me bro please

Comment: Can't help you if you don't try to run the query on PhpMyAdmin

Comment: your script is lot of helped me thank you very much